# How to change an ATM class during run time (Java Reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

There is an ATM GUI .class.

In the ATM class, if the user click swipe, it will use Java reflection to dynamically call my Card.class.

In the ATM class there is this variable:

```
int userBalanceField = 100;
```

I am trying to dynamically change it to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Here is the swipe function in ATM:

```
    Object object;
    Class class_ = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader;
    this.printToScreen("Loading Card");
    String string = "." + File.separator + "Card.class";
    File file = new File(string);
    ClassLoader classLoader2 = classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    try {
        object = new URL("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Card.class");
        class_ = Card.class;

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException var6_7) {
        var6_7.printStackTrace();
    }
    object = "Card";

    this.printToScreen("Reading card data and verifying ATM");
    try {
        Method method = class_.getMethod("swipe", ATM.class);
        Data data = (Data)method.invoke(null, this);
        if (data == null) {
            this.printToScreen("Machine considered invalid");
        } else {
            this.user = data;
            this.tempEntry = "";
            this.screenState = 2;
            this.updateScreen();
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException var8_11) {
        this.printToScreen("Security Exception when swiping card.");
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException var8_12) {
        this.printToScreen("No Such method exception when swiping card.");
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException var8_13) {
        this.printToScreen("Illegal Argument exception when swiping card.");
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException var8_14) {
        this.printToScreen("Illegal Access exception when swiping card.");
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException var8_15) {
        this.printToScreen("Invocation Target exception when swiping card.");
    }
```

Here is my attempt.

```
    public static ATM.Data swipe(ATM anATM){ 

    Class atmClass = anATM.getClass();
    try {
        Field moneyInMachineField = atmClass.getDeclaredField("moneyInMachine");
        System.out.println("Loading field..." + moneyInMachineField.getName());

        Field userBalanceField = atmClass.getDeclaredField("userBalance");
        userBalanceField.setAccessible(true);


        ATM.Data result = new ATM.Data(cardNumber, accountNumber, name, pinNumber);
        userBalanceField.set(result, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        return result;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException 
            | NoSuchFieldException 
            | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I keep getting "Invocation Target exception when swiping card."

Answer (score 2):

The syntax that you are using is for the creation of new non-static inner classes. `Data` is a static inner class of `ATM`, so you want to do the following:

```
ATM.Data result = new ATM.Data(cardNumber, accountNumber, name, pinNumber);
```

According to the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this
>   syntax:
>
> OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
>        new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();

If `Data` was non-static, it would contain a specific reference to ATM (which would give it the ability to refenence AMT.this.userBalance), but it is only used as a POJO.

In addition to the above, you are setting the field incorrectly. When calling `field.set()` you need to provide it with the object which contains the field and the value you want to set it to.

In your case it would be:

```
userBalanceField.set(anATM, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

See [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

Comment: Now I get a run time exceptions from the ATM class when swiping.

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace?

Comment: The ATM class won't tell. It throws an exception after moneyInField.

Comment: Try, `userBalanceField.set(anATM, Integer.MAX_VALUE);` It will set the userBalanceField of the object anATM to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: WHO R U? You are a genius!

Comment: I've been trying to do this for ages!

Comment: @HuyVo haha updated the answer, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Field userBalanceField = atmClass.getDeclaredField("userBalance");
```

suggests that `userBalance` is a field of `ATM`, but

```
ATM.Data result = new ATM.Data(cardNumber, accountNumber, name, pinNumber);
userBalanceField.set(result, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

tries to set the field `userBalance` of `ATM.Data` object.

If the field `userBalance` is in `ATM.Data`, try:

```
Field userBalanceField = ATM.Data.class.getDeclaredField("userBalance");
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: userBalance

Comment: userBalanceField is in ATM.

Answer (score 0):

The InvocationTargetException *wraps* all exceptions thrown by reflected methods. This is because the Reflection API is oblivious to the types of exceptions that methods can throw.

Try catching:

```
InvocationTargetException
```

And then use:

```
getCause();
```

For example:

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getCause();
}
```

This will tell you what is ***actually*** going wrong. It will also help us to debug your code.